# Do you need to deploy SASS in production?

Tags: css, git, sass, production

Do we need to include the SASS file in production? Can't we just deploy the compiled CSS output? How do you guys deploy your CSS/SCSS code in production?

If any of you don't include SCSS in production how do you deal with version control like Git. I assume the master version should have the SCSS file there, but pulling from production environment it should be excluded? Is this problematic?

I just want to see what the most efficient way to do this.

The reason I asked this is because, using Chrome DevTools lately I've been seeing scss files as source. To see what I mean, if you go to getbootstrap.com and inspect its styles, you'll see scss as the source.

Comment: No, you do not need to deploy anything that is a part of your **build** process, only the output of it. Obviously you keep the SCSS files on your Git, so I don't really understand the question. such questions are better asked on Reddit. *Stackoverflow* is for very specific problems and not a general workflow questions as this one

Comment: The reason I asked this is because, using Chrome DevTools lately I've been seeing scss files as source sometimes. To see what I mean, if you go to https://getbootstrap.com and inspect its styles, you'll see scss as the source.

Comment: Ok. So how do you deploy version control? Do you just do a .gitignore on the production side? @vsync if you don't really understand the question you probably should just keep quiet.

Comment: @japonix - you are seeing SCSS files in out devtools because of [`source map`](http://thesassway.com/intermediate/using-source-maps-with-sass) files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The **browser does not render or understand SASS** code. Thus serving such files for the sake of styling not only is not required but it doesn't even work¹.

¹ <sub>Well, yeah, it *can* work—there're many SASS implementation, including a [JavaScript](https://sass-lang.com/libsass#javascript) one that can be used in a browser.</sub>

The SASS code you see in your browser's developer tools (not just Chrome) is a **developer tool**. In order to diagnose CSS issues you can instruct your SASS compiler to generate [source maps](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#sourcemap-option). A source map is a document that links positions in your possibly minified CSS files to the SASS source code it comes from. When you open your developer tools and the CSS file declares a source map ([example](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css)):

```
/*!
 * Bootstrap v4.1.3 (https://getbootstrap.com/)
 * Copyright 2011-2018 The Bootstrap Authors
 * Copyright 2011-2018 Twitter, Inc.
 * Licensed under MIT (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/LICENSE)
 */:root{--blue:#007bff;--indigo:#6610f2;--purple:#6f[…]
/*# sourceMappingURL=bootstrap.min.css.map */
```

… the browser downloads the map ([example](http://:https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css.map)) which in turn links the corresponding SASS source code files.

```
{"version":3,"sources":["../../scss/bootstrap.scss","../../scss/_root.scss","../../scss/_reboot.scss"[…]
```

Together with the file/line/column mapping information, developer tools can reconstruct the SASS code where a given element styles come from.

```
"mappings":"AAAA;;;;;ACAA,MAGI,OAAA,QAAA,SAAA,QAAA,SAAA,QAAA,[…]
```

The source files are obviously not required. Whether to include them or not depends on factors like:

1. Is it okay to distribute them or they contain stuff that's meant to remain private like internal comments or intellectual property?
2. Do you need to diagnose stuff in the live site?

[image: Get Bootstrap]

Comment: In 2021 most browsers understand sass, BUT compiling is still encouraged for performance and compatibility.

Answer (score 2):

Sass is converted to CSS, So you don't need to install it on the server. It only needs to be installed locally, Browser only understands CSS, SAAS is a preprocessor scripting language make your code easy to organize and edit with a little effort.

Comment: The reason I asked this is because, using Chrome DevTools lately I've been seeing scss files as source. To see what I mean, if you go to getbootstrap.com and inspect its styles, you'll see scss as the source.

Comment: This is because they're including the Sass sourcemaps on the production site so Chrome is aware of what CSS rules are from what Sass files.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your build process. If you push Sass files and compile on the webserver when you run your deployments then yes. But I have a file structure something like this:

```
- src
--- styles
------ Sass files
--- js
--- images

- build
--- assets
------ styles
--------- CSS files
------ js
------ images
```

So I push everything into git and before I deploy changes to live I run my build commands* locally then push everything into Git.

From here, I deploy everything within the `/build` directory up onto the webserver for my site.

* My build commands are my regular compiling commands except I minify on build only.